# Reading .xlsx file as a stream

Tags: node.js, excel, xlsx

I am using xlsx package https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

I am trying to read an xl file of size 50 MB having 50 columns and around 175,000 records.
It takes too long(75 seconds) to read file using

```
// starting at time t = 0;
const xlValue: xlsx.WorkBook = xlsx.readFile(filePathToExtractDataFrom, {
    cellDates: true,
    dateNF: "DD-MM-YYYY",
});
const sheetNameList: string[] = xlValue.SheetNames;
const xlJsonData: any = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(xlValue.Sheets[sheetNameList[0]]);
// completing at time t=75;
// start working on xlJsonData, operations of type: modify values, check values
```

Is there any other way to read it faster?

I need to do some processing over the data after converting it to json format.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
fs.createReadStream('path/to/file.xlsx');

const workbook = new XLSX.stream().xlsx.read(stream);
```